# ios , get float level mic updateMesters when mic is recording audio

Tags: avaudioplayer, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

here is my code for recording now how can get the level sound input in mic by sample UIlable float number

i think i will use this function but how can i use this in rec.h & rec.m file

**(void)updateMeters**

```
AVAudioSession * audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
NSMutableDictionary* recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
recordedTmpName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.0f.%@", [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] * 1000.0, @"aac"];
temporaryRecFile= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:recordedTmpName]];
recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:temporaryRecFile settings:recordSetting error:nil];
[recorder setDelegate:self];
[recorder prepareToRecord];
[recorder record];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During recording, you have to call updateMeters periodically, and get the average power by 
- (float)averagePowerForChannel:(NSUInteger)channelNumber

```
[recorder setDelegate:self];
[recorder prepareToRecord];
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
[recorder record];
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(handleTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];




- (void) handleTimer
{
    [recorder updateMeters];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"lf",[recorder averagePowerForChannel:0]];
}
```

To see more information, you can visit **[AVAudioRecorder Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)**